# how to get the differences in a list

Tags: python, list, join, tuples, difflib

Below are the two lists of tuples:

```
text1_lines = [('a','1'), ('b', '2'), ('c','3')]
text2_lines = [('a','4'), ('z', '5'), ('c','6')]
```

I can get the differences with below code

```
d = difflib.Differ()
diff = d.compare(text1_lines,text2_lines)
diff_list = '\n'.join(diff)
```

Please suggest how can I convert `diff_list` into a list, so that I can iterate through the list.

Comment: ... remove the `join`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
d = difflib.Differ()
diff = d.compare(text1_lines,text2_lines)
diff =  list(diff)
for item in diff:
    print(item)
```